# Opening a Word document with .doc extension with Eclipse SWT OleClientSite in Java

Tags: java, swt, ole

I'm working on a program that uses the Eclipse SWT OleClientSite (in Windows 7) to open a Word document inside an RCP application. For the past two years, this program has called the following constructor:

```
OleClientSite clientSite = new OleClientSite(oleFrame, SWT.NULL, new File(documentFileName));
```

Since the latest update to SWT, this constructor now throws an exception when attempting to open Word documents with a ".doc" extension. Word documents with a ".docx" extension are still functioning correctly. The problem seems to be that OleClientSite isn't properly recognizing ".doc" as a Word extension, since explicitly inputting this information with the following constructor works:

```
OleClientSite clientSite = new OleClientSite(oleFrame, SWT.NULL, "Word.Document", new File(documentFileName));
```

This constructor comes with a warning, however, stating that it is never to be used:

> IMPORTANT:This method is not part of the public
>           API for OleClientSite. It is marked public only so that it
>           can be shared within the packages provided by SWT. It is not
>           available on all platforms, and should never be called from
>           application code.

Oddly enough, even though this constructor explicitly says it should never be used, it is [used on the Eclipse SWT Snippets Website as an example of how to open a .doc file](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet262.java)...

If anyone has any pointers, I'd greatly appreciate it. So far my options seem to be either to forbid my users from using ".doc" files or to roll back to an old version of SWT.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267343/nullpointerexception-thrown-when-instantiating-and-olecontrolsite-on-windows-7?rq=1 , but there was no resolution in that question.

Answer (score 0):

The current Eclipse version supports opening a Word-Document (*.doc) from the navigator view. It uses the class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.editorsupport.win32.OleEditor` to open the document in an Editor-Part. I would suggest, you take a look at the code at [1] and adapt the needed parts to your scenario.

[1] http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.win32/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/editorsupport/win32/OleEditor.java

Comment: I just tried this, and unfortunately Eclipse sent me the same error that I get in my old client code.

"Failed to create Ole Client. result = -2147221164."

Eclipse's own exception handling also gives a reason:

"Cannot create the in-place editor. This is probably because there is no OLE editor registered against the type of file you were trying to open."