# Saving XLS in OLE editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

If you use the 64bit Eclipse IDE, most old Office formats (DOC, XLS, PPT) won't even open. So it really shouldn't be surprising that the SWT framework can't handle them either. You can force [these files to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054905/opening-a-word-document-with-doc-extension-with-eclipse-swt-oleclientsite-in-ja?noredirect=1&lq=1) using deprecated API, but even then you can't store XLS files for some reason.

Standalone test:

```
final File file = // insert file here
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setText(file.getName());
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
shell.setSize(800, 600);

OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
frame.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
final OleClientSite clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Excel.Sheet", file);

Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
button.setText("Save");
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> clientSite.save(file, true));

shell.open();

while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
    }
}
display.dispose();
```

There is no exception, no log, no nothing. It just doesn't save. `OleClientSite.isDirty()` is not set to false either.

How do I save XLS files using the OLE framework of SWT?